# How can i generate a user token that can serve me all audiences even if they don't have a country?

Tags: api, facebook, graph, facebook-marketing-api, audience

Is there anyone who can help me please!
I generated a user token using the graph api tool explorer.
then I launched this api: https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/act_xxxx/customaudiences?fields=name&access_token=xxxx
in order to read all similar audiences, but there are some similar audiences that I can't read with this api.
I noticed this when I visited this link: https: //www.facebook.com/adsmanager/audiences
1- also, I debugged the API used with Facebook (in this interface :  https: //www.facebook.com/adsmanager/audiences) that it was using to fetch all audiences and I take the token used, and when I take that token my API successfully fetched all audiences.
2- I did some research and i found that this API cannot retrieve audiences that don't have a country.
so how can i generate a user token that can serve me all audiences even if they don't have a country ????